# A calling app to replace my default calling app

Tags: android, phone

I am looking for a calling app to use instead of my Sony Xperia Z2's default calling app. For the search I already did I got a bunch of "free calling" and "fake calling", etc. apps. Actually, my phone has a problem that makes the other call party not hear clearly my voice. I am pretty sure it is software-related and so I wonder if there is a calling app I can use as a substitute.

Features list:

- It should be free (free trial is also OK if it is a paid app)
- It should be able to dial any number and make a regular phone call (voice) just like the default Dialer app
- I do not need it to access the Internet, so it should preferably not ask for Internet access permission
- Accessing contacts is not much desirable, but it is OK

I already tried some apps like Truedialler and Clever Dialer, but do not actually make a call. Rather, they show a menu for "complete the action using" where you select the default system Dialer of the phone. I want a complete and independent dialing dialing and calling app.

Comment: What features do you need? Reading between the lines, it should be free-of-cost – or is paid OK (how much?) as long as there's at least a free version to try/evaluate first? How important is privacy in this context (considering such an app will need to dial-out plus access your contacts, while it might require the `INTERNET` permission as well)? For a selection, be welcome to see my app listing for [Contact Managers and Dialers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_dialer).

Comment: Thank you @Izzy for the list. There seems to be a couple of good options there.

Comment: Especially in sensitive areas, I try to point out "good candidates" (here: watch out for the "no internet" remarks) and "bad ones" (usually if they failed an audit; yellow triangles or red exclamation marks for those). Watch the numbers in the yellow-background boxes (numbers of permissions); with Javascript enabled, clicking the app name gives more details. // Thanks for your update, and fingers crossed for good recommendations!